# Does 'using' close an existing open connection?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

When doing the following, is the connection closed and disposed of, even if it was already open beforehand?

```
using (var conn = myDbContext.Database.Connection)
{
     //Do something...
}
```

Comment: Yes of course. But the connection will be pooled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter whether the connection was open, what matters is that it *wasn't* disposed, and after your `using`, *is* disposed and can no longer be used, even though `DbContext` (sensibly) assumes that you won't go and dispose of its connection behind its back, will continue attempting to use the connection later, and will fail. So don't do that.

In your particular example, the connection would be disposed when `DbContext` gets disposed, and should not be disposed manually, and should definitely not be disposed earlier.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but you shouln't be using it like that in my opinion.

If you dont initialize your object, in a using statement, you shouln't close it in one eather.